# Zend locale number format

Tags: zend-framework, locale, number-formatting

I would like to set up number decimal delimiter based on selected locale, and while I can do this:

```
Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber($number, array('locale' => $locale, 'precision' => 2));
```

It doesn't quite work 'globally'. Is there a way to say to format all numbers across the app to conform to selected locale?

Zend version is `1.12`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default Locale at Bootstrap.php

```
Zend_Locale::setDefault('pt_BR');
```

But it will not work for the `precision` option